# Why does magento catch wrong event from admin section?

Tags: magento, events, dispatch, adminhtml

I have set up a default 'no modifications' copy of magento on a local machine to replicate the results on our production machine.

When I try to catch the event 'adminhtml_customer_save_after' in a module, it always returns / stops on customer_save_before. This is also true for any of the customer_save_after type events.

Adding

```
file_put_contents('/tmp/events.log','Dispatching '. $name. "\n",FILE_APPEND);
```

to the dispatchEvent function in /var/www/app/Mage.php verifies that it indeed does return on customer_save_before, even though that is not the event i'm asking for.

Please validate this and let me know if this is intended functionality. I must have access to the entity_id in magento admin section when our call center / order team creates new customers in the admin side of the site (for placing phone-in orders) for synchronization with our company's database.

PHP from module

```
<?php
class NKI_CustomerSync_Model_Observer
{

public function AddCustomerToQueue($observer)
{

$event = $observer->getEvent();
$customer = $event->getCustomer();

$model=$event->getModel();

echo "<PRE>";
var_dump($event->getName());
var_dump($event->getData());

var_dump($event);
var_dump(get_class_methods($event));
die();
}.....
```

XML

```
<config>
<modules>
<NKI_CustomerSync>
<version>0.1.0</version>
</NKI_CustomerSync>
</modules>

<global>
<events>
<adminhtml_customer_save_after>
<observers>
<NKI_customersync_model_observer>
<type>singleton</type>
<class>NKI_CustomerSync_Model_Observer</class>
<method>AddCustomerToQueue</method>
</NKI_customersync_model_observer>
</observers>
</adminhtml_customer_save_after>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, since your post betrays a few misunderstandings about how Magento's event system works, which in turn is leading you to diagnose the problem incorrectly, here's a quick review of the event system.

The `dispatchEvent` method in `Mage.php` is the wrong place to check if Magento "catches" your event.  This method receives **all** events.  It's not until deeper in the calling chain, in `Mage_Core_Model_App`'s identically named `dispatchEvent` method

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php
public function dispatchEvent($eventName, $args)
{
    foreach ($events[$eventName]['observers'] as $obsName=>$obs) {    
        //...
    }
}
```

where Magento will look for any event observers (or in your parlance, event catchers)

Magento issues **all sorts of events** on every request.  The `customer_save_before` event is issued whenever a customer model object is saved.  This includes saving both on the frontend and the backend.  However, the `adminhtml_customer_save_after` event is fired here

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/CustomerController.php
public function saveAction()
{
    //...
    $customer->save();
    //...
    Mage::dispatchEvent('adminhtml_customer_prepare_save', array(
        'customer'  => $customer,
        'request'   => $this->getRequest()
    ));        
    //..
}
```

In other words, this event fires in the `saveAction` of the admin customer controller.  In other other words, this event fires after a user clicks "save" in the Magento admin console when looking at an individual customer.

So, **both** the `customer_save_before` and the `adminhtml_customer_save_after` event will fire when a customer gets saved in the Magento admin.  The `customer_save_before` event fires first, and then the `adminhtml_customer_save_after` event fires.

As for your specific code, what you've shown looks correct.  That assuming you have the closing `}` on the observer class, and that it's in the correct location.

```
app/code/community/NKI/CustomerSync/Model/Observer.php

//or, if your module is configured in the local code pool

app/code/local/NKI/CustomerSync/Model/Observer.php
```

and that your module's `config.xml` has a closing `</config>`, is valid XML, and is in your module's `etc/config.xml` file.  This also assumes Magento can see your module.

I used your code to throw together a skeleton module and your event fired when I saved a customer on the backend of Magento.  That skeleton module [is here](http://alanstorm.com/2013/projects/NKI_CustomerSync.tar).  Compare it to what you have to see where your module may be subtly incorrect.

Comment: Alan, thanks for helping again. Always to the rescue with a great explanation. Yes, I agree my question is a little baffling sounding when I read it back the next day. I do want to clarify that I may have some of the terms incorrect and I did manage to not paste the full code.Sorry bout that. When I tried your module on both of my machines, the result was the same. It will die() but the event name displayed onscreen is customer_save_before, not adminhtml_customer_save_after, which is what I would expect to display. Also I wasn't trying to catch events in Mage.php, i was logging the chain :)

Comment: Sigh. clearing the cache helps too. After doing this, your module works fine. Magento has the power to make you feel like a moron in 2 point 5 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

The Event Should be put in adminhtml and is called customer_save_after